# When do you say two clocks are asynchronous?

Tags: digital-logic, clock

I have a situation where reference clock of PLL_0 is coming from some clock source and giving out a clock (named C0) with freq0 and and C0 is going as reference clock to PLL_1 and giving out clock C1 and C1 is going to PLL_2 and giving out C2.

Please see the below figure for better understanding.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9Rs0F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the above situation can we say that clocks C2, C1 and C0 are synchronous to each other?

Note: I would like to add that freq0, freq1 and freq2 are not integer multiple of each other.

Comment: Clocks are asynchronous when not in-phase or their frequencies are not multiple of the other.

Comment: Why do you need this word? They are certainly not independent but it would look to be a lot of hassle to interface other things using single cycles of the various clocks.

Comment: The only way C0, C1, and C2 would be synchronous (to a "high" degree), would be if Clock Source is the input to all three (they would be in parallel, not series), and the frequencies are integer multiples of the Source frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understanding meaning of "asynchronous"/"synchronous" may vary depending on the context but in very most cases synchronous means that events happen at a **fixed phase relation**.

So in your case I'd say yes, the clocks are synchronous because phases are fixed (=locked < **P**hase **L**ocked **L**oops), although they may have different frequencies and although there may be some small jitter (phase noise).

Comment: If frequencies are not integer multiple of each other, does the phase locking still come into consideration?

Comment: As Long as the ratio is a rational number I'd say yes.

Comment: If \$f_0 / f_1 = T_1 / T_0 = m / n\$ (where \$m\$ and \$n\$ are more or less small integers) look at phases of events with respect to frequency \$f = \frac{1}{T_0 T_1}\$. After \$T=T_0 T_1\$ all periodic events will happen again (repeat) with same phases.

Comment: @Curd A irrational ratio of, say, sqrt(2) would probably still be "locked", although it would be more impressive. :)

Comment: @pipe: and I'd be curious about the implementation of a PLL that is able to generate irrational frequency ratios.

Comment: To be pedantic, me thinks *"there may be some small jitter "* nullified the rest of this answer.

Comment: @Trevor: clocks generated by PLLs will always have added jitter (because PLLs are control loops) but phase error will not accumulate, i.e. phase will NOT drift away. As long as the jitter is small the generated clock is still synchronous. That's what I wanted to say by "there may be some small jitter" and I think it doesn't contradict the rest.

Comment: Curd, yes I understand that, but the instantaneous edge movement from cycle to cycle is in no ways synchronous. For example, you could not use the PLL clock to sample the source clock since the PLL edges would vary from occurring before and after the source clock edges. i.e. definitely not synchronous.

Comment: Yes, true, but that doesn't contradict the definition of synchronous I've given. I just say that events (e.g. clock edges) happen at (about) the same phase compared to some reference clock. If this is true for **both** signals I'd call them synchronous. And of course you have to allow some finite tolerance (phase error), therefor the *about*. I would not require that clock edges of the signals in question always have to happen in the same order (as you seem to do).

Comment: Yup, I agree, but synchronous is one of those black and white things... it either is or it isn't. With a PLL it really hardly ever is, rather it oscillates around synchronism. BUt it depends on what you do with the clocks too, in many instances it's close enough.

Comment: Doesn't that mean they'll only be in phase for 1/(T0*T1) cycles? The rest of the time they'll be out of phase and therefore asynchronous the rest of the time?

Comment: @horta: (BTW: actually I should have written above \$f=\frac{1}{mnT}\$). No: because synchronous does not mean **in** phase, it means **fixed** phase (with respect to some common reference clock). The clock edges will happen at the same phase values *all the* time.

Comment: Where are you getting your definition of "fixed" phase = synchronous? It's almost like you're saying that any signal that keeps a *consistent* frequency is by your definition synchronous. I don't see how that definition is useful in any manner.

Comment: No: if the frequency ratio of two signals is not a rational number (fraction of two more or less small integers) or just not constant or slowly drifting apart (even if one is 1.000000MHz and the other is 1.000001MHz) then they are not synchronous. They may still be synchronous if one is 1.00MHz and the other is 1.01MHz for a very short time (a few cycles) but then going back to e.g. 0.99MHz etc.. Synchronicity is about phases not about frequency. The point is that clock edges happen at fixed phases with respect to some reference clock.

Comment: Again...where is your definition coming from? Also, according to your definition, they're still synchronous if they're off by 0.00000001MHz if they're consistent because at all time, they are aligned and in phase to an imaginary reference.

Comment: @horta: No, that's not true. That's not what I said. If they are (constantly) off by 0.00000001MHz they can not be synchronous to a constant reference clock. Then both clocks will drift apart: e.g. if the are in phase at t=0 they will will have a phase difference of 180° after 50s.

Comment: Right, so if you have two different frequencies, no matter what they are, they will not be in phase except once in a blue moon even if they are set up by the same reference clock.

Comment: @horta: very simple counter example: If one clock is 2MHz and the other is generated by dividing 1st clock by 2 it will by 1MHz (obviously a different frequency) but of course it will be synchronous to the first one: every 1µs they will be in phase (not once in a blue moon). Is it really so difficult to understand?

Comment: But for the rest of the time (infinite amount in between integers) they will be out of phase.

Answer (score 3):

> can we say that clocks C2, C1 and C0 are synchronous

Yes. The whole *point* of a PLL is to "lock" one frequency to another (phase, actually, but it turns out to fix the frequency too). They *could* be asynchronous if the PLLs are malfunctioning, in which case the output from the PLL could be a free-running clock (worst case).

Two clocks are asynchronous if they do not depend on each other, for example two free-standing oscillators at the exact same frequency will still be asynchronous, since you will always have a small amount of drift and an unknown phase at startup.

Answer (score 3):

I would be **very cautious** in stating that the frequencies are synchronous.

With ideal PLLs that had no phase jitter then you may be able to make that claim, but in reality there will be some variation in the clock edge timing. As such, if you were driving logic using multiple clocks there may be asynchronous race conditions dictated by that phase jitter.

The clocks may be "in-tune" but synchronous is an over-statement. In reality, a PLL will be in a continual state of going in and out of synchronism. Whether that is "close enough" with a specific design of PLL for your particular requirements is another matter.

Comment: So what's YOUR defintion of synchronous then?

Comment: @Curd same as yours, it's just that real PLLs don't quite give you that *"fixed phase relation"*. They do over n-cycles, but not cycle to cycle.

Comment: A very good and not only hypothetical distinction.

Comment: @Trevor: but also clocks derived from other clocks not by PLL but by counters (or any other combination of logic gates)  *do* have some added jitter (as you can never guarantee that gates will switch at exactly the same threshold). The jitter is just much smaller than that of PLLs. It's just difference in quantity not quality.

Comment: @Curd true, but divider type circuits tend to have fixed rise and fall phase delays so have that "fixed phase relation". Anyhoos.. you get my point, "some caution is pertinent".

Comment: @Trevor: Have you really looked at input and output clock signals of a "real PLL"? You won't see any phase change during a n cylce period with the bare eye if the loop is locked. The jitter is very small (or the PLL is very bad). Normally the control loop has a low pass filter whose time constant is substantially larger than n periods, i.e. much larger than one cycle.

Comment: @Curd that's exactly my point. The derived clock will skew either side of the fundamental frequency over a time defined by that filter. It's only the aggregate frequency that is synchronized. As such you can't reliably use the derived clock to digitally sample the fundamental clock or it's derivatives anywhere near the fundamental edges without particular attention to those paramaters.

Comment: @Trevor: I agree completely... but that problem doesn't affect the question whether the two clocks should be called synchronous or not. BTW: you can get the same problem if you generate two clocks by two different clock dividers (race conditions).

Answer (score 2):

Just judging from a dictionary definition, I would say these are only synchronous for a likely tiny fraction of the time. Synchronous means happening at the same time. These PLL's tick to the same beat once in a blue moon if they're not integer multiples of each other. For 99.99%+ of the time they are asynchronous. There's no logic you could drive from these separate blocks that you could ever call synchronous. Within each of the PLL's domains, you can have synchronous logic, but if you're looking at all of your logic combined with all 3 of the PLL's domains, it becomes asynchronous to each other.

Comment: I agree. Especially if independent clock trees are created for each PLL you have to consider them asynchronous to each other.

Comment: Two clocks being synchronous does NOT mean that both clock signals must have edges at the same time.

Comment: @Curd That's the only way synchronous logic will work together.

Comment: According to your understanding a 2MHz clock and a 1MHz clock derived from the first by a divide-by-2 clock divider can not be synchronous because clock edges do not happen at same times.

Comment: @Curd Indeed. They are now asynchronous. That's the only way digital logic will work together which is the main area where I've heard synchronous vs asynchronous. 1MHz logic doesn't interact with 2MHz logic unless you've got special asynchronous mechanisms in place to account for this difference.

Comment: @horta: What is "1MHz logic" or "2MHz logic"???

Comment: What's useful about a signal being synchronous relative to a clock is that any meaningful event that happens with the signal will occur at a time which is definitely before the clock or definitely after.  If a PLL is rigged to e.g. make the rising edges of a double-frequency clock coincide with the rising edges of a symmetric source clock, then if the PLL is locked it should be possible to treat the source clock as synchronous relative to *falling* edges of the output clock since no edge of the source clock should happen near a falling edge of the output clock.

Comment: @Curd logic which has been created to run at those frequencies of course.

Answer (score -1):

Well no they are not synchronous in the definition, they are linked,you have a primary source, but you have delay and loop bandwidth issues,a PLL is always 'chasing' an error signal,and it is defined by the settling time of the loop? So in effect it is always playing 'catch up' , having cascaded feedback loops gives rise to a very unstable design, (audio? Oscillation), furthermore it is frequency dependent, as there will be filtering effects, so the loop bandwidth is ill defined? If you want more info, my email is: patrickhogan1969@gmail.com, i hope i can help a fellow out with a problem?
Pat Hogan (Msc EPD)